# Pandas groupby object filtering

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, conditional-statements

i have a pandas dataframe

```
df.columns
Index([u’car_id’,u’color’,u’make’,u’year’)]
```

I would like to create a new FILTERABLE object that has the count of each group (color,make,year);

```
grp = df[[‘color’,’make’,’year’]].groupby([‘color’,’make’,’year’]).size()
```

which will return something like this

```
color   make   year     count
black   honda  2011   416
```

I would like to be able to filter it, however when I try this:

```
grp.filter(lambda x: x[‘color’]==‘black’)
```

I receive this error

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

How do I leverage a 'groupby' object in order to filter the rows out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then output is `DataFrame`. Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[['color','make','year']].groupby(['color','make','year'])
                                .size()
                                .reset_index(name='count')


df1 = df[df.color == 'black']
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware of the (reset_index) part. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

***Option 1***
Filter ahead of time

```
cols = ['color','make','year']
df[df.color == 'black', cols].grouby(cols).size()
```

***Option 2***
Use `xs` for index cross sections

```
cols = ['color','make','year']
grp = df[cols].groupby(cols).size()

df.xs('black', level='color', drop_level=False)
```

or

```
df.xs('honda', level='make', drop_level=False)
```

or

```
df.xs(2011, level='year', drop_level=False)
```

Comment: The first option would be unnecessarily expensive as it would require calculations at each filter request.  The second option does work, however, and can be used as an alternative to the method presented by @jezrael

Comment: @chattrat423 jezrael's answer is perfect.  This was purely to add alternatives.

Comment: Understood. I wasn't aware of the (xs) method for pandas either. This was a great addtion